# How to connect Google Data Studio to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a Google Cloud SQL database that I can connect to with my SQL client. However, I have not been able to connect Google Data Studio to the Google Cloud SQL database with the Cloud SQL data source. I have the IP address and credentials from Google Cloud SQL.

My guess is that Google Data Studio cannot connect to Google Cloud SQL because I need to add an IP address to allow the traffic into Google Cloud SQL but Google Data Studio does not have or does not publicize an IP range.

Has anyone had success connecting to Google Cloud SQL using the Cloud SQL data source in Google Data Studio?

Comment: Take a look at this article:  https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/7020436?hl=en&ref_topic=6370347

Comment: Did you have the chance to add the CIDR mentioned in the Help Center article provided by @Kamran ?

Comment: @George yes, doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting any error messages while trying to connect? Which connector are you using?

Comment: To confirm, you added each of the [listed](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/7020436?hl=en) IPs/Ports to your Cloud SQL [access list](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external#appaccessIP) ? If so, are you using First or Second generation Cloud SQL instance. Also is your IP IPv4 or IPv6? You may want to also consider making a new [use](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users#creating) specifically for this connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since August 2017, Google Data Studio connects natively to Google Cloud SQL databases:

> The current version of the connector no longer requires whitelisting,
>   and it provides encryption; however, to use these features, you must
>   create a new data source using the Google Cloud SQL connector.

See [Google Cloud SQL connector](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020436?hl=en&ref_topic=6370347) in help for detailed description on how to create a connector.

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering, this only works if you're using a MySQL Cloud SQL instance -- not with Postgres.

Answer (score 4):

The following ranges need to be whitelisted for Data Studio to work:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Comment: i have added these CIDR notation listings and I still do not have access.